# Debugging web containers in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, wildfly

When I add various servers (Wildfly/Tomcat) run/debug configurations I can attach theirs source code in application servers configuration window.

[image: Wildfly configuration with attached source code]

[image: Tomcat configuration with attached source code]

I would expect this source can be browsed while debugging. Unfortunatelly it can't:

[image]

I want to trace the process of deployment on various containers. I know I can open source code in another IntelliJ and connect remotely but I want to debug my application and application server in the same window. What shall I do to do it?

Comment: What is the issue? Are you looking for the `org.jboss.invocation` source code?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to trace how different containers handle my application. How it's deployed, how requests are served etc.

Comment: I *thought* there was a way for IDEA to automatically download them, but maybe it requires a POM. WildFly has several projects that feed into it so you'd need to download the source for each one of those as well. There's going to be a lot debugging to sort out those things :)

Answer (score -1):

I see arquillian source code not WildFly in your configuration

Comment: When you open wildfly source code you can see many components. Aqruillian is only the first on the list.